# What is the default path for cpanm to install Perl modules?

Tags: default, perl-module, cpanm

Before I use `cpanm` to install some Perl modules on a "new" (to me) system, I would like to know where they will get installed by default.

I don't see any kind of a dry-run option, which is what I'd hoped for.

`perl -V` includes this %ENV and @INC info:

```
%ENV:
  PERL5LIB="/home/randall/perl5/lib/perl5"
  PERL_HOMEDIR="1"
  PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/randall/perl5"
  PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base /home/randall/perl5"
  PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/randall/perl5"
@INC:
  /home/randall/perl5/lib/perl5
  /usr/local/lib64/perl5
  /usr/local/share/perl5
  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/lib64/perl5
  /usr/share/perl5
```

Does that define the behavior, or are there other considerations?  Specifically, the documentation for cpanm includes:

> ```
> -l, --local-lib
>     Sets the local::lib compatible path to install modules to. You don't
>     need to set this if you already configure the shell environment
>     variables using local::lib, but this can be used to override that as
>     well.
> ```

But it does not indicate which environment variables are significant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be of help: https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Where-does-this-install-modules-to?-Do-I-need-root-access?

> **Where does this install modules to? Do I need root access?**
>
> It installs to wherever ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build are configured to (via `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT`).
>
> By default, it installs to the site_perl directory that belongs to your perl. You can see the locations for that by running `perl -V` and it will be likely something under `/opt/local/perl/...` if you're using system perl, or under your home directory if you have built perl yourself using perlbrew or plenv.
>
> If you've already configured local::lib on your shell, cpanm respects that settings and modules will be installed to your local perl5 directory.
>
> At a boot time, cpanminus checks whether you have already configured local::lib, or have a permission to install modules to the site_perl directory. If neither, i.e. you're using system perl and do not run cpanm as a root, it automatically sets up local::lib compatible installation path in a `perl5` directory under your home directory.